# Read part of XML with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am trying to read just this part of some big xml file:

```
---------------------

<SOL>
  <LineDisc>109.90</LineDisc>
</SOL>

---------------------
```

and I found the way to do it but I have some question.

```
        string testElement;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();


        doc.Load(xmlFilePath);

        XmlNodeList companyList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("SOL");

        foreach (XmlNode node in companyList)
        {
            XmlElement companyElement = (XmlElement)node;

            testElement = companyElement.GetElementsByTagName("LineDisc")[0].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(companyElement.SelectSingleNode("LineDisc").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(testElement);

        }
```

The first way of accessing the node by tag name works nice, but my question is, why I can't achieve the same thing with  `SelectSingleNode`?

Comment: what are you getting when you use `SelectSingleNode` ? any error ?

Comment: @MostafizurRahman Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @analogvoyager do you have any namespace defined on root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml namespaces

```
var namesp = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namesp.AddNamespace("name", "http://ratequote.usfnet.usfc.com/v2/x1");

XmlNode companyList = doc.SelectSingleNode("//name:SQL", namesp).FirstChild;
```

Comment: Indeed, this did it : companyElement.SelectSingleNode("//name:LineDisc", namesp).FirstChild.Value. Thanks a lot!